# finding the next prime number in pascal

Tags: primes, pascal

I am trying to find the next prime number after the number the user enters in and i have to do it in pascal . I don't even know what to start with , could anyone help me?

```
program PRIME;

uses crt;

var

C, N : INTEGER;

const

A=2;



Begin PS:

Writeln ('enter your number' )  ;

Read (N);

begin

Writeln(

 readln;

End.
```

Comment: Guess you are trying to get somebody to do your homework

Comment: There is no known formula to discover prime numbers other than taking a list of knowns and using that or brute force testing every possibility.

Comment: Create array of primes lesser than Input and for each number bigger than Input try dividing by each element of prime array, if you're able to find at least one prime factor then move on, stop until you find integer with zero factors.

Comment: It is a homework , but im a noob in pascal, I know you can write " IF it does something , THEN do something else" but can you write "IF it DOESN'T do something then do something else" ???

Comment: @user3088719 - Read the lecture notes/text book

Comment: @user3088719 me? anybody can do that

Comment: no i'm just asking is that possible , and how!

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." You haven't made any effort at all to calculate anything, and the code you've posted won't even compile as do-nothing code. If you can't get started on your homework, ask your instructor for extra help - you've either not been paying attention in class or they have not yet earned their share of your tuition dollars by providing you with an education.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare n-element array of bools (primes values are true), where n is a number entered by user and multiplied by two. Then find all primes up to n using sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm (remove all composite numbers changing their values to false). After that, finding next prime number after entered value will be easy. Indexes of true values are prime numbers.

Try to write your own code and then edit your question if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Two hints:

- if the number entered is < 2 then the next prime is 2.
- if the number entered is >= 2 then the next prime is an odd number greater than the number entered and less than twice the number entered (Bertrand's Postulate).

No, we won't write your Pascal code for you.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in solving this problem is figuring out how to do it by hand. From wikipedia:

> A simple but slow method of verifying the primality of a given number
>   n is known as trial division. It consists of testing whether n is a
>   multiple of any integer between 2 and sqrt{n}.

So if you are given 6, you would first test the number 7 to see if it is prime. You test if 7 is prime by dividing all the integer numbers from 2 to the square root of 7(2.645751311). So you have to only test to see if 7 is divisible by 2. If the user enters 14, you have first test to see if 15 is divisible by any of the integer numbers from 2 to the square root of 15 (3.872983346). So you would test to see if 15 is divisible by 2 or 3.

There are two loops involved. One is adding 1 to the input number repeatedly - that is - if they input 10, you test 11 for primeness, then 12, then 13, then 14, then 15, etc. The other loop is dividing all the integer numbers between 2 and the square root of the current number being checked for primeness. Divide it by 2, is there a remainder?  Divide by 3, is there a remainder? Divide by 4, is there a remainder? And so on. Each time you get a division with no remainder you can stop that loop since you know that you have not found a prime and need to increment the value and recalculate your square root and start dividing again.

In Free Pascal it looks like this:

```
program NextPrimeNumber;

uses
   Math;


var
   user_input : integer;
   next_prime : integer;


function CalculateNextPrimeNumber(value :  integer) : integer;

var 
   next_prime_not_found :  boolean = true;
   square_root      : integer = 0;
   i            : integer = 0;
   remainder        : integer = 0;
   result       : integer = 0;
   successful_divisions : integer = 0;


begin
   (* loop through the numbers above our value till we find one that
      is not divisible *)
   while next_prime_not_found do
   begin
      successful_divisions := 0;
      value := value + 1;
      square_root := trunc(sqrt(value));
      (* try and divide by all the numbers between 2 and the square root of
         out current number (square root value truncated 
         to next lowest integer) *)
      for i := 2 to square_root do
      begin
         DivMod(value,i,result,remainder);
         if remainder = 0 then 
         begin
            successful_divisions := successful_divisions + 1;
            (* this is a non-prime number, so quit trying more divisions *)
            break;
         end;
      end;
      if successful_divisions = 0 then
         (* we found a prime so stop looking by setting the value 
            the while loop is checking to false *)
         next_prime_not_found := false;
   end;
   CalculateNextPrimeNumber := value;
end;


begin
   writeln('enter a postive number');
   readln(user_input);
   next_prime := CalculateNextPrimeNumber(user_input);
   writeln('the next prime number after ',user_input,' is ',next_prime);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a,y,i,k:qword;
f:text;
begin
    assign(f,'numere.prime');
    reset(f);
    while not eof(f) do 
    begin
        readln(f,i);
    end;
    close(f);
    repeat
        k:=0;
        inc(i);
        reset(f);
        while not eof(f) do 
        begin
            readln(f,a);
            if i mod a = 0 then 
            begin
                inc(k);
                break;
            end;
        end;
        close(f);
        if k=0 then 
        begin 
            append(f);
            writeln(f,i);
            close(f);
        end;
    until i=10000000;
end.
```

This program writes all the prime numbers below 10000000 in a file. Later, you can write a new program that checks if the entered number is in that file. (On the first line of the file is '2')